# what to do Share point 365 doesnt have the feature for sitemailbox?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, workflow

I am a newbie to the share-point world.Now there is no site-mailbox feature in Sharepoint 365.Because of this **I assume my send email from the workflow is not working**.After searching for the alternatives,I saw blogs that suggests to use office 365 Team to do it.How can I do this.Can someone elaborate on the steps.More important is my assumption correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SharePoint Online no more supports new site mail boxes. Existing site mail boxes created prior to March 2017 should work I think.

Recommended way is to use Office 365 Groups. When you create a new team site a group will get auto created for it. It will include all of the members of the site. You can find the group from Mail App -> Folder -> Team site name

Once you set this up you can use Sent Email activity for sending emails to that group.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply.But my problem is the same.When I went and checked the  ail App -> Folder -> Team site name there was nothing.Therefore I created a new group. But don't know how to link my sharepoint site to thise o365 group? The only thing I want is to get mails through my workflow but that is not happenning :(

Comment: Using O365 group with existing site - this feature will be only available in 2018.. for now the existing sites works fine with site mailboxes..

Comment: Cool ..Thanks a lot for your reply.To Reiterate  for sharepoint online it doesnt matter whether we have sharepoint site mailbox added or not as it doesnt allow to add.But it will work like previous version.And my mail thing is working now ,it was previously failing due to some other reason.